# AppKernel.php not found on Symphony 5.3.7?

Tags: symfony, symfony5

I tried to follow the following tutorial https://bitgandtter.wordpress.com/2015/09/10/symfony-a-restful-app-security-fosoauthserverbundle/ to install OAUTH2 on symfony.

Nevertheless, there is no more an AppKernel.php file (everything works very well with the server).

I think that this file has been renamed to Kernel.php, but with this new versions I can't follow the tutorial (write new FOS\OAuthServerBundle\FOSOAuthServerBundle() inside).

So, is this step is no more needed with newers versions of symfony or I have to do something else?

Answer (score -1):

Check your `config` folder: there should be a `bundles.php` that also contains references to the other bundles you've installed.

But as the repository for `FOSOAuthServerBundle` hasn't seen that many commits in the last months, you should probably use any other OAuth bundle like [`knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle`](https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle) or [`hwi/oauth-bundle`](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle) instead